# "It is not understandable TO me" Vs. "It's not understandable FOR me"

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition is the natural out of these two in the following context?

> "It is not understandable **TO** me"
>
> "It's not understandable **FOR** me"

I've heard both of them and I'm not sure what's more natural.

A context for example:

> Person A: speaks and explains a topic in math, and wants to make
> more efforts and continue to explain it by drawing, while person B has
> already understood it and this stage is needless.
>
> Person B: Thank you! It's already understandable to / for me!

Another context for example:

> A teacher who explains a subject to his students, and wants to confirm
> that they understood it well. Now, I now that it's possible to ask
> them "Did you understand that?" But he has the choice to ask them in
> another way: Is it understandable? Or is it understandable for / to
> you?

Comment: I can understand it.

Comment: [Google Ngrams suggests that *understandable **to** me* is vastly more common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=understandable+%2A+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cunderstandable%20%2A%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bunderstandable%20to%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bunderstandable%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bunderstandable%20by%20me%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Downvotes for what? I don't have a problem to be criticized, but I'd love to know what the reason is, in order to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

Both work, because "understandable to" is a phrase. If we used a different adjective:

- *It's easy **for** me* —this works because "for me" is used with many adjectives to mean "in my experience."
- *It's easy **to** me* —this doesn't, because "easy to" is not a phrase the way "understable to" is not an established phrase.

So both "understandable to" and "for" are natural enough. I would probably choose "to," but can't say for sure why.

Comment: "understandable FOR" may also introduce the thing that is understood, e.g. "It is understandable for the kicked dog to snarl" and then has nothing to do with the party doing the understanding.  For this reason "TO" is much clearer here, "FOR" is at risk of forming a [garden-path sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence).

Comment: I find neither expression very idiomatic in many contexts, but could accept them in some limited ones.  More context would have been helpful.  Another issue is that "understandable for me" can also mean: "People understand that such a situation is to be expected in my case."  In other words, it is not clear out of context, who is supposed to be understanding what.